# how to put text under image view

Tags: android, xml, textview

I wrote some xml but still cant place the text on the center of the screen as image.
I want to put the text after my image.
On my xml just trying to put text on the center under the image. 
my xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    android:gravity="fill" >

    <ViewFlipper
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/flipper"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:flipInterval="2000" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Linear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/logonews" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/imageLabel"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Israel News"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ViewFlipper>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the [`CompoundDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3adrawableTop) doesn't meet your needs, you may use a `RelativeLayout` instead of a `LinearLayout` like this:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/logonews" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/imageLabel"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Israel News"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

Considered using textview with drawable on top? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableTop

in xml: `android:drawableTop`