# How to implement on click listener for horizontalscrollview

Tags: android, android-layout

I have implemented HorizontalScrollView to show image. but i cant find way to implement onclick listener for particular image click on HorizontalScrollView.

i have implemented onclick on imageview 1 also i setid during imageview called but on toast message it only shows "14"..

anybody please help me

**Updated**

Thanks to sam he point out error;
Now i want to display text below every image.
so i am trying to implement relative layout and following code but it does not working.

Here is my code

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.cfragment, container, false);
    }
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    /** Setting the multiselect choice mode for the listview */
    initfrag();
}
private void initfrag() {
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
     TextView tv1 = new TextView(getActivity());
     tv1.setText("xyzxyzyxyzxyz"); tv1.setId(1);
     TextView tv2 = new TextView(getActivity());
     tv2.setText("xyzxyzyxyzxyz");tv2.setId(2);
     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
             RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
     lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, tv1.getId());
     layout.addView(tv1);        
     layout.addView(tv2, lp);
    final LinearLayout linearlayout1 = (LinearLayout)getView().findViewById(R.id.container);
    LinearLayout linearlayout2 = (LinearLayout)getView().findViewById(R.id.container2);
    LinearLayout linearlayout3 = (LinearLayout)getView().findViewById(R.id.container3);
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) { 
        iv = new ImageView(getActivity());
        iv.setPadding(20, 5, 5, 5);
        iv.setId(i);
         iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.test_play_image);
         linearlayout1.addView(iv, 200, 220);
         ImageView iv2 = new ImageView(getActivity());
         iv2.setPadding(20, 5, 5, 5);
         iv2.setImageResource(R.drawable.test_play_image);
         linearlayout2.addView(iv2, 200, 220);

         ImageView iv3 = new ImageView(getActivity());
            iv3.setPadding(20, 5, 5, 5);
             iv3.setImageResource(R.drawable.test_play_image);
             linearlayout3.addView(iv3, 200, 220);
             iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    int s =iv.getId();
                    Toast t = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "id is "+s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    t.show();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get the id of the View that you just clicked, not the last View created in your loop. So simply change the variable in your OnClickListener from `iv`:

```
int s =iv.getId();
```

To `v`, the View passed to `onClick()`:

```
int s = v.getId();
```

Comment: thanks.. how stupid i am ..i forgot this little thing.thanks again....can you help me again that i want to add text below image so how can arrage textview below image using relative layout?..i have updated main question please check updated part.

Comment: I don't see where you add the LinearLayouts to the RelativeLayout... Are the images aligned next to each other (horizontally) or on top each other (vertically)?

Comment: <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >
    <HorizontalScrollView 
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScroll"
    android:background="#C6D7D2" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  >        
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>

Comment: Here is xml 1st one is linear layout than into that i used horizontal layout and into that horizontallayout i used Linearlayout than i close horizontal-layout and main linear-layout...i am addding imageview and textview by coding(programaticaly)..i want to show textview below every image in horizontal layout.

Comment: I would set up my layout like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10195557/1267661).

Comment: dude i am asking you how can i code to show textview below imageview programmatically? in horizontalscrolview

Comment: Err, yes. Inside my HSV, I would use a LinearLayout to hold a series of TextViews with the attributes `drawableTop` and `gravity` (no ImageViews necessary) *or* I would use a RelativeLayout with `layout_below` and `layout_toRightOf` to position my ImageViews and TextViews. These are the basic approaches mentioned in the question above, whether it is written in XML or Java the attributes are the same. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks sam it helps me to organize textview below image view.. but i am facing weird problem that this layout works perfect on jellybean but on gingerbread or lower android horizontalscrol didn't work at all..it having horizontal scrolling problem on lower version.. do you have any solution for this?

Comment: Thanks guys. I was searching for this for like, hours.